# Creating animations using native javascript

Tags: javascript, animation

I am interested in creating various kinds and types of javascript animations using traditional javascript (no frameworks) and canvas. My question is can anyone point me to resources (books/sites etc) that would be useful. I know that many frameworks already exist but my learning object is to understand the core language.

Comment: @neitony If you want to understand the core language, get the ECMAScript specification. Animations are NOT part of the core language. Not even setTimeout is part of the core language.

Comment: @Sime - There's a combination of confusion in that statement, the language is an *implementation* of ECMAScript, it's not strictly bound to it, it can have additional features as well - for example the JavaScript specification maintained by Mozilla.  Also, *no* DOM elements or methods are part of JavaScript (which is a language, not an object model), so that's related, but an entirely different area really.

Comment: @Nick The language is an implementation of ECMAScript? Isn't ECMAScript the language? And the implementations are just that - implementations. We could say that each browser defines a dialect of the language, but there is only one "core language" (and this is a quote from the OP) and that is ECMAScript.

Comment: @Nick Of course, I am assuming that whenever someone says JavaScript, that he means ECMAScript, and not the dialect of the language that exists in Mozilla browsers. I assume that this assumption is justified :)

Comment: @Sime - JavaScript has additional constructs not exclusive to ECMAScript was more my point, so the "core" of what's available, even cross-browser is above and beyond ECMAScript.

Comment: @Nick I would say that the "core" of what's available cross-browser is not above but below the ECMAScript spec, since none of the browsers implement the spec to its entirety. I am not aware of features in implementations that are cross-browser and that are not in the ECMAScript spec. When someone refers to JavaScript as a language, what he means is the subset of features that are cross-browser, and this subset is a subset of the features defined in ECMAScript.

Comment: @ime - There are *several* examples of *very* useful features not in ECMAScript, for example native JSON support (something I use every day), keep in mind that JavaScript evolved and added features for a **decade** before ECMAScript went from 3rd to 5th edition (with no 4th in-between).

Comment: @Nick You mean the JSON object? That's in the 5th edition.

Comment: @Sime - it is *now* yes, but it wasn't there for years while it was in JavaScript and widely used.  You're *assuming* people mean ECMAScript when they say JavaScript, that's a false assumption...ECMAScript's 5th edition was (mostly) a subset of features added and actively use in JavaScript.  This is a bit pointless at this point since it's a chicken/egg argument.  What I'm trying to convey is *don't assume*, especially with ambiguous terms - no matter what the subject...but *especially* JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animation is basically an **attribute change over time**. To achieve this you use `setInterval` to make sure the change takes effect **gradually**. In every step you calculate the current value of an attribute by **interpolating** between two values, considering elapsed time. As a final touch you can add **easing** to your animations to make transitions look smooth between states. Animation queues can also be added.

**Recommended - [Roll Your Own Effects Framework](http://fronteers.nl/congres/2009/sessions/roll-your-own-effects-framework)** *by Thomas Fuchs*

Answer (score 0):

There is a [plethora of articles discussing this](http://www.bing.com/search?q=javascript+fade+animations&form=DLCDF8&pc=MDDC&src=IE-SearchBox), available on the intertubes.

One key technique is to use setTimeout() to modify the opacity of an item, stepwise.  This is basically what jquery UI - one of the frameworks you mentioned - does to implement animations, fades, slideouts, etc.

Comment: somebody didn't like my answer?  Too easy I guess?